# NoSuchMethodError when initialising actors in Scala 2.8

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-2.8, actor

I recently downgraded to Scala 2.8, and now whenever I try to initialise an actor, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.actors.ReactorCanReply$class.$init$(Lscala/actors/ReactorCanReply;)V
```

Apparently [this guy](http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000831?comment=58534643) had the same problem, but no solution was found. Has anyone else encountered this and solved it?

I thought that maybe there was some sonfusion going on in the background between Scala 2.8 and 2.9 files, so I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Scala and Eclipse, deleting all my binaries and rebuilding, and even creating a new Eclipse project and copying my source files in, but the problem persists.

My stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.actors.ReactorCanReply$class.$init$(Lscala/actors/ReactorCanReply;)V
at uk.mike.blackjack.PlayerReceiver.<init>(PlayerReceiver.scala:11)
at uk.mike.blackjack.Blackjack$.main(Blackjack.scala:141)
at uk.mike.blackjack.Blackjack.main(Blackjack.scala)
```

Comment: Are you mixing Scala 2.9.x binaries with 2.8 binaries? That usually leads to these sorts of errors.

Comment: Could be. I tried deleting and rebuilding all my binaries, but maybe Eclipse is doing something weird.

Comment: Some more context (like maybe the stack trace) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The Java bytecode compiled from Scala is not backward-compatible. You must recompile all your scala file and their dependencies when you upgrade to any new Scala version before Scala 2.10 releases.

BTW: Scala 2.10 promises to keep backward-compatible between all 2.10.x versions in the future.